# Access denied occurs after translate menu link

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

I want to translate my menu, I have installed internationalization, variable and locale modules but on my menu items when I click on translate :

[image]

An access Denied page is displayed :

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT]
Log :
[image]

Comment: You need to check the permission

Comment: What's in Drupal's watchdog?

Comment: @Bala: All admin permissions are checked

Comment: @Molot: I have edited my post

Comment: @Bibix I hope this has been answered already

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to make sure the menu is translatable.  Do this by clicking on the "Edit Menu" option and clicking on "*Translate and Localize. Menu items with language will allow translations. Menu items without language will be localized.*"

The click "Save".

The path would be as follows: ***site***/admin/structure/menu/manage/***menu_id***/edit

Comment: Thanks you. I can add my translation. But the menu is still not translated while the site content is translated... I'm out of this post scope but if you have an idea

Answer (score 4):

you must first assign a language other than the default "language neutral" to the existing menu items (click edit for the menu item). Once a source language has been assigned, the translate link should work.

Answer (score 0):

do you need to enable the option in admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu/edit

you have three option choose the middle one...

i hope i help you!

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you try to rewrite your answer? Now I'm not even sure if you are asking for additional details, or really answering, and if later, what exactly you meant.

Answer (score 0):

When you have entered the menu item via the **menu import**, if you have selected **language undefined** during the import process for the new menu items, then trying to translate those menu items results in access denied.

If you **re-edit** those menu items, then you can translate them.

This works for the menu option "Translate and Localize. Menu items with language will allow translations. Menu items without language will be localized."

Comment: See this related post too:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2316659